# How to search content of a list from a large file quickly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file, 3 gigabytes in size.

I want to search the content of a list from that file quickly.

Someone suggested converting the CSV to a BLF file and apply a bloom filter.

I am a beginner and I don't have any knowledge regarding it.

It would be very helpful if anyone could provide a short working code or a link to a page that has a detailed explanation regarding the same.

Comment: Need more details, please. Can you edit your post with few lines of your file? Do you have to search this file often? What is your use case?

Comment: @Corralien, I have to run my program in a loop to create separate files of people from different cities. Link to few lines of my CSV file: https://pastebin.com/SAh8TcAY

Comment: the second last part of the line is the city

Comment: Does the first line of your file is an header (column names)?

Comment: No, it doesn't have a header

Comment: Sorry to annoying you but do you need to often use this file or it's just a one-shot?

Comment: yes, I need to use the file often. And it's okay that is not at all annoying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your file to a database (SQLite):

```
import csv, sqlite3

# Change column names
fields = ('code1', 'code2', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'genre', 'city', 'country')

# Create the database and the unique table
con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE tbl {fields};")

# Read the csv file and insert rows to database
reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv'))
cur.executemany(f"INSERT INTO tbl {fields} VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", reader)

# Create some indexes to increase speed of queries
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX idx_fullname ON tbl (firstname, lastname);")
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX idx_location ON tbl (city, country);")

# Commit and close (Mandatory!)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

After that, you have some choices to query the database:

- sqlitebrowser
- Python/sqlite (like above but with SELECT statement)
- Pandas ([pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html))

Comment: Thank you so much @Corralien for answering my question, it really did help me. I really want to upvote but, I do so as I have a low reputation. Sorry for that.